# How to use a qSleep in Mainwindow.cpp in Qt?

Tags: qt4

I am having the following function in delay.cpp

```
void QTest::qSleep(int ms)
    {
        QTEST_ASSERT(ms > 0);

    #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
        Sleep(uint(ms));
    #else
        struct timespec ts = { ms / 1000, (ms % 1000) * 1000 * 1000 };
        nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
    #endif
    }
```

and it is defined in delay.h as

```
 void qSleep(int);
```

I am want to use this function in mainwindow.cpp in Qt. when i am using this function in a member function of Mainwindow,

```
void MainWindow::xyz()
{
    qsleep(1000);
}
```

compiler says it is not declared in this scope even though i have included delay.h in mainwindow.cpp.can anybody tell me how to use it?

Comment: is `MainWindow` inherited from `QTest`?

Answer (score 1):

You've declared your `sleep` function as a member of the `QTest` class, so you can't call it like a free function. Make it a static member of `QTest` and then you can:

```
QTest::sleep(time);
```

But it's a bad idea to sleep in GUI code: it freezes your application. That's not user-friendly.

You should try and do what you're trying to achieve with a `QTimer` to delay a call or some similar strategy.